# PerformancePoint stacked bar

Tags: sharepoint, performancepoint

I'm trying to get a report with stacked bars in the panel PerformacePoint control. 
I have 3 sets and want to get version reaching the target visually. 
If I use a bar graph, and use a value formatted as%, first, it works. But when you step to the line with stacked bar disappears objectives. Any idea? Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "step to the line with stacked bar"?